# .ajax() form submission error

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to submit a form using .ajax() jquery function

```
function submitForm()
{
    $("#quiz").ajaxForm({
               target: '#result',   
              type:   'post',
              beforeSubmit: before_submit,
              success: showResponse

           }).submit();
 }
```

the problem is form gets submitted in second attempt i.e. when i click twice.

Comment: Could you show us where and when you call the submitForm function?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function() {

    var fname     = $('#fname').attr('value');
    var lname     = $('#lname').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "fname="+ fname +"&amp; lname="+ lname,
            success: function(){
                $('form#submit').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});

            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Initializing it in the `$(document).ready(function())` ? I hope not. 
First initialize it in the document ready minus the `submit()` method and call `submit()` in the `submitForrm()`

The things inside `ajaxform()` must be initialized before calling them that is why most jquery plugins or widgets are initialized in the document ready section.

That is why when you call it for the first time it is initialized and on the second time it is actually executed.